# Prefuse : Adding edge weights to the GraphView Demo

Tags: java, visualization, prefuse, graphml

I am using the prefuse visualization toolkit, The GraphView Demo in the toolkit is amazing providing a variety of controls to visualize the data.

I am able to generate GraphML for my dataset and visualize it using GraphView, One additional thing that i would love to have is to label the edges with weights or color coding to demonstrate the strength between two nodes.

Any input about the same are greatly appreciated..Thanks..

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I haven't worked with the API just checked the documentation:) It seems that the API has an EdgeRenderer interface that you should implement to achieve the desired behaviour.

Ref: http://prefuse.org/doc/manual/introduction/example/, http://prefuse.org/doc/api/prefuse/render/DefaultRendererFactory.html

Update: First a correction: in fact EdgeRenderer is not an iterface but a class. I've made a simple demo to illustrate how to implement custom edge rendering.

### Feature

Add label to edges containing the initials of the node labels

### Method

I made a quick and dirty solution, that is copied LabelRenderer and modified in order to handle edges.

### Code

I named the class as `MyEdgeRenderer`:

```java
public class MyEdgeRenderer extends AbstractShapeRenderer {
```

use the original `EdgeRenderer` to draw edge lines (see `render()` below for the renderer in action):

```
protected EdgeRenderer m_edgeRenderer = new EdgeRenderer();
```

modify `getText()` to get the initials from nodes:

```
protected String getText(VisualItem item) {
    EdgeItem edge = (EdgeItem)item;
    VisualItem item1 = edge.getSourceItem();
    VisualItem item2 = edge.getTargetItem();    

    String t1 = null, t2 = null;
    if ( item1.canGetString(m_labelName) ) {
        t1 = item1.getString(m_labelName).substring(0,1);            
    };
    if ( item2.canGetString(m_labelName) ) {
        t2 = item2.getString(m_labelName).substring(0,1);            
    };
    if (t1 != null && t2 != null)
        return t1 + "-" + t2;
    else
        return null;
}
```

modified `getAlignedPoint()` to position the label half way on the edge:

```
protected void getAlignedPoint(Point2D p, VisualItem item, 
        double w, double h, int xAlign, int yAlign)
{
    double x=0, y=0;                

    EdgeItem edge = (EdgeItem)item;
    VisualItem item1 = edge.getSourceItem();
    VisualItem item2 = edge.getTargetItem();

    // label is positioned to the center of the edge
    x = (item1.getX()+item2.getX())/2;
    y = (item1.getY()+item2.getY())/2;      
    ...
```

modify `render()` to (I) first draw the line and (II) use black color:

```
public void render(Graphics2D g, VisualItem item) {         
    m_edgeRenderer.render(g, item);
    ...

    // render text
    int textColor = ColorLib.color(Color.BLACK); // item.getTextColor() 
    if ( text != null && ColorLib.alpha(textColor) > 0 ) {
    ...
```

For testing I modified the sample found on the Prefuse website (http://prefuse.org/doc/manual/introduction/example/Example.java):

```
    // -- 3. the renderers and renderer factory ---------------------------

    // draw the "name" label for NodeItems
    LabelRenderer ir = new LabelRenderer("name");
    ir.setRoundedCorner(8, 8); // round the corners

    // draw the "name" initials for EdgeItems
    MyEdgeRenderer er = new MyEdgeRenderer("name");
    er.setRoundedCorner(8, 8); // round the corners

    // create a new default renderer factory
    // return our name label renderer as the default for all non-EdgeItems
    // includes straight line edges for EdgeItems by default
    vis.setRendererFactory(new DefaultRendererFactory(ir, er));
```

This is just a demo to illustrate custom rendering. In real you would probably retrieve label text and color from the graph model, ie: `EdgeItem.getString(), getTextColor()`. I guess both attribute could come from the GraphML data. Also the example code shows how to set colors for nodes, it might be adapted for edges as well (though I haven't tried):

```
    // -- 4. the processing actions ---------------------------------------
    ...
    // use black for node text
    ColorAction text = new ColorAction("graph.nodes",
            VisualItem.TEXTCOLOR, ColorLib.gray(0));
```