# How can I show weight of edge using prefuse jar files

Tags: java, swing, graph, applet, prefuse

I am using Prefuse lib and creating a directed graph.

For creating a graph, I used

```
Graph g= new Graph(nodeTable,edgeTable,directed)
```

edgeTable includes

> columns sourceNode, targetNode and weight

of the edge.

I need to show the weight of the edge.

Comment: May be you should refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010823/prefuse-adding-edge-weights-to-the-graphview-demo

Comment: If this is _not_ a duplicate, please edit your question with a [mcve] that shows your current approach.